# Add . to print(time) - python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I am trying to write a program to print the current date (year month day hour minute and seconds) in a human readable format, like: `[Today is 2015-09-17 and it is 09:34:35.]`.

I tried to manually add a "." at the end like  ~datetime.time(9,31,35), "."))~

What I am currently receiving as **the error**:
{
The format seems wrong:

Today is 2021-09-03 and it is 09:31:35 .
^
Expected a dot here, not a space.
}

This is **the code**:

```
    import datetime
    datetime.datetime.now()

    print("Today is", datetime.date(2021,9,3), "and it is", datetime.time(9,31,35))
```

Comment: "I think I need to add a variable to specifically call the date and the time separately" Well, did you try looking in the documentation for `datetime` to see if it offers a way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We don't care about your skill level and we aren't really interested in anything beyond *the question*, and possibly some explanation of why you have that question.

Comment: I think you may be getting thrown by the fact that the `datetime` module contains a `datetime` class. So you need to use `datetime.datetime.date` and `datetime.datetime.time`. The easiest way to use these methods is to create a `datetime` object, e.g., `dt = datetime.datetime(2015,9,17,9,34,35)`, then use methods of that object: `dt.date()` and `dt.time()`.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp  dt = datetime.datetime(2015,9,17,9,34,35).   okay I think I get what you're saying. . . so the  "dt" is a variable not a prebuilt in name and can be assigned anything. Its just for others to know what it is and ease of naming in this case (dt = datetime) just like many would do "tk" for the tkinter module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean by:

```
date = datetime.datetime(2015,9,17,9,34,35)
print("Today is ", date.date(), "and it is ", date.time())
```

Comment: is date.date() and date.time() in a different import than datetime it threw an error. I'm also using python 3.8 I'm not sure if that could make a difference to why it threw an error.

Comment: @navi `date` is the variable name, edited my answer

Comment: Okay so in the print() command you're appending the variable date to date() with the [date.date()] am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: I did use your edit it did fix the initial question. I did also try to upvote I do not have enough reputation for it to count though unfortunately.  now I'm supposed to have a "." at the end for it to submit properly